# How to return date format "Jan 29, 2014" from new Date object

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use `var d = new Date()` I get a huge string like:

`Wed Jan 29 2014 11:36:56 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`

How do I just return this:

`Jan 29,2014`

Without using `substring`, etc to parse it out the string, is there a natural function that will do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13452892

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/432347

Comment: Those links don't give specific info about this particular format. I've looked at the `getMonth` and `getYear` functions, doesn't do it either.

Comment: If you are able to use some library, try moment.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var str = months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getDate() + ", " + d.getFullYear();
console.log(str);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/68B5Z/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
d.getMonth();
d.getYear();
```

etc...

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Maybe d.toDateString() is the easiest solution.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. JavasCript Date Library is quite dirty. I suggest you to use **DateJS**. I'm sure you will get whatever you need about dates and time with this library easily.

[Here the link to DateJS](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/)

Regards

Comment: _"JavasCript Date Library is quite dirty."_ What does that mean? And why on earth should he use an entire library for something so basic?

Comment: ^ Agreed, using an entire library is much dirtier than creating a function to do it in this particular format only.

Comment: It means in my opinion that you have to write a few lines for get a basic thing like is date and time. I used Javascript Own date library and then I used DateJs. I don't know if you're a big fan of Javascript Library and I hurt you telling this but it's my experience and my opinion.

Edit: I hope you are not trying to make a calendar hahah, just kidding.

Comment: @Zee Tee Honestly,I just only see a poor person who is crying for help because have no idea about how to print the day in he lives in a computer screen. Also I see that you are this kind of people that this community didn't need.Pathetic

Comment: Yup, you figured me out lol

Answer (score 0):

There's also [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/); simple yet powerful.